# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function st_geomfromtext()

Tags: sql, pdo, fatal-error

I am changing my code from a standard sql insert to using PDO and params.

I thought I had an issue with my code, however after checking my error log I get this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function st_geomfromtext()

Does this mean PDO doesn't support that function?

php 5.1.6 PostGIS version 2.01 Postgresql 9.2

Answer (score 1):

PDO has nothing to do with this function. Nor PHP does.
It's **sql** function and have to be called from within sql **query**, not from PHP scope.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but how come see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013080/using-pdo-for-an-insert-and-the-geom) it works in the sql format but when I use PDO statements I get the fatal error?

Comment: **It have to be called from within sql query, not from PHP scope.**

Comment: Ok, I wasn't entirely sure what you meant by that, could you elaborate please. Thanks